Setting inducing points to non trainable in Gaussian Process regression
I notice that on the GPflow tutorials for Stochastic Variational Inference they choose a certain amount of inducing points, and after that they make them not trainable.
Here they set it to not trainable:
minibatch_size = 100

# We turn off training for inducing point locations
gpflow.set_trainable(m.inducing_variable, False)


def run_adam(model, iterations):
    """
    Utility function running the Adam optimizer

    :param model: GPflow model
    :param interations: number of iterations
    """
    # Create an Adam Optimizer action
    logf = []
    train_iter = iter(train_dataset.batch(minibatch_size))
    training_loss = model.training_loss_closure(train_iter, compile=True)
    optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

    @tf.function
    def optimization_step():
        optimizer.minimize(training_loss, model.trainable_variables)

    for step in range(iterations):
        optimization_step()
        if step % 10 == 0:
            elbo = -training_loss().numpy()
            logf.append(elbo)
    return logf

I don't understand the reason for it, or is it strictly necessary? Are there any theoretical implications on not learning the inducing locations?
